# custom wait for try catch webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a piece of code that will need to be stored in try catch block.

here is the piece of code. I'm talking about

```
    try{
        this.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

        this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("PegaGadget0Ifr")));


    } catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e.toString());
    }
```

As I have is set up right now it works but if frame is not available it will wait 60 seconds before proceeding into catch is it possible to set custom timeout for a try catch block.

I was thinking implicitlyWait() would do the trick(thinking if frame is not available implicitly wait will try to pool DOM object for 3 seconds and then move to catch) but it does not seems to work.But it still waits 60 seconds before timing out and stating that

```
'Timed out after 60 seconds waiting for frame to be available:'
```

can anyone point me how to maybe modify wait build in timeout. or set a timeout on try catch block so I don't have to wait 1 minute if frame is not available and just continue the script?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer my self. essentially what i needed to do is to modify the explicit wait in the try condition. so the wait step that comes after will wait the amount of seconds you specify.

here is the code example

```
try{


    WebDriverWait customWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 2); //2 is for seconds before timingout

    customWait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("PegaGadget0Ifr")));


} catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println(e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the above try catch block, you are making your code to check first and then wait until your expected condition becomes true.So for this it will keep on waiting till the timeout has occurred or your condition is true like element is found or not. So the actual modification might not hold in your case.

Other way could be if lets say(assumption from end), you can wait for the page to be and then you check for the IFrame is available or not (since assuming once the page is loaded IFrame will also be loaded). You can certainly check that.

```
  driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Above code is for waiting till your page is loaded. Also if you have a different requirement it would be great you can post more example on how are you waiting for IFrame ? Is IFrame is loaded later after the page is loaded ? More info..

Comment: thank you for the replay, essentially when page is loaded it has different buttons and some of this buttons open "tab" that is a frame and sometimes the frame gets detached (due to javascript load) from the page so I get Stale Element exception. so what this line of code does this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.id("PegaGadget0Ifr"))); is waiting for a frame to be fully loaded before doing some operations. sometimes the waits is needed as stated before but most of the time its not when frame is not detached there is not need to wait for the lead.

Comment: but what this try catch block does is waiting when the reloading frame is not needed. and it consumes lot of time doing so full 1 minute before timing out.

Comment: how about adding 1 more condition for checking whether the page actually contains the Iframe element or not, if it has the element then wait otherwise come out try catch block();

Assert.assertTrue(driver.getPageSource().contains(textOnThePage));


so this will check whether your page source has Iframe or not and based on that you can wait or not wait.

Comment: how would it check if frame is present? I know it will be containing iframe as the script wound not run at all if frame did not show up. but in one step of execution there is a possibility frame being detached. and that is i use try block to reload it if it happens. what i'm looking for if there isn't necessary  for iframe to reload. the wait step just wait for couple of seconds not full minute.